# How can I remove the browser-added blurred border on focused form elements?

Tags: forms, html, google-chrome, input, border

I’ve built an HTML form for an email signup. When you click in the email input's textarea, a blurred gray border surrounds it in Chrome. How can I turn this off?

http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/7Hs2r/

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `outline: none;` on the CSS for the input element.